# Adding cell after looping on PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, phpspreadsheet

I intend to put the total column after the looping yet I don't know how. Here's my code,

```
$i=5;
    $no=1; 
    foreach($laporan as $data) 
    {
    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $no)
    ->setCellValue('B'.$i, date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data->add_time)))
    ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $data->nama_penyaluran)
    ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $data->nominal);
    $no++;
    $i++;
    }
```

There must be one more column below the table for total. Thank you.

Comment: you can just echo out the total count of your $laporan like this echo count($laporan) and you can also wrap it in a if condition so only if count is greater then 0 then it will show the total count

Comment: just add as other column `->setCellValue('E'.$i, $total);`

Comment: @BlackXero well, the thing is the data is dynamic that it won't be that simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like This Way to Display total end of your all data display. [DEMO SHEET](https://ibb.co/1rGXNBx)

```
$i=5;
    $no=1; 
    foreach($laporan as $data) 
    {
    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $no)
    ->setCellValue('B'.$i, date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data->add_time)))
    ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $data->nama_penyaluran)
    ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $data->nominal);
    $no++;
    $i++;
    }
$i = count($laporan);
 $i2=$i+6;

 $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$i2, 'Total');
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$i2, 'Your Total varible $total');
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$i2, '');
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$i2, '');
```